# Matlab crashes when invoking functions from intel MKL

Tags: fortran, mex, intel-mkl

I'm trying to link `Fortran` code with `Matlab` using the `Mex` function. I can successfully compile and link the code using the following instruction:

```
mex COMPFLAGS="$COMPFLAGS -Qopenmp -Qmkl"...
'-IC:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\mkl\include'...
'-LC:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\mkl\lib\intel64'...
-lmkl_intel_ilp64.lib -lmkl_intel_thread.lib -lmkl_core.lib libiomp5md.lib...
ero_dep_fortran.F Module.F prepare_bank_collapse.F LINEAR_ELASTIC_STIFFNESS.F FAILURE_CRITERION.F OUTPUT.F pardisonew.F
```

However, when I execute the generated `.mexw64` function, Matlab crashes without any error information. Then I debug my `Fortran` code line by line, and I found that `Matlab` crashes when invoking the function `pardiso` which comes from Intel MKL library. It seems that when invoking function from MKL, Matlab will crash and I have no idea how to fix it. 
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

PS: Thanks for the help from @Evg. Finally, the following instruction works:

```
mex COMPFLAGS="$COMPFLAGS -Qopenmp"...
'-IC:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\mkl\include'...
'-LC:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\mkl\lib\intel64'...
-lmkl_intel_ilp64.lib -lmkl_intel_thread.lib -lmkl_core.lib libiomp5md.lib...
ero_dep_fortran.F Module.F prepare_bank_collapse.F LINEAR_ELASTIC_STIFFNESS.F FAILURE_CRITERION.F OUTPUT.F pardisonew.F
```

Previous Additions:
I also try to run the code on the Intel Parallel Studio XE 2017 compiler using makefile as:

```
ifort Module.F OUTPUT.F FAILURE_CRITERION.F pardisonew.F LINEAR_ELASTIC_STIFFNESS.F prepare_bank_collapse.F ero_dep_fortran.F /Qopenmp /Qmkl /nostandard-realloc-lhs /MD -o BANK_COLLAPSE.exe
```

The generated .exe works. So the problem is not due to the code self or the function `pardiso` from Intel MKL library. I guess there is something wrong when  Matlab invokes `pardiso`, although it 'seems' to link sucessfully.

I use Matlab 2019b and Intel Parallel Studio XE 2017 for Fortran with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 to compile and link the code.

The full output after compiling mex with `-v`option is

```
Verbose mode is on.
... Looking for compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2017 for Fortran with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'IFORT_COMPILER17' ...Yes ('C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\').
... Looking for file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\Bin\intel64\ifort.exe' ...Yes.
... Looking for folder 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows' ...Yes.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 14.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 14.0 ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7' 14.0 ...Yes ('C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\').
... Looking for file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe' ...Yes.
... Looking for folder 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC' ...Yes.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1' InstallationFolder ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1' InstallationFolder ...No.
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1' InstallationFolder ...Yes ('C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\').
... Looking for registry setting 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Kits\Installed Roots' KitsRoot10 ...Yes ('C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\').
Found installed compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2017 for Fortran with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015'.
Set PATH = C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\bin\intel64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\VCPackages;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\..\Common7\IDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\..\Common7\Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\\Bin\x86;;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\mpi\intel64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.210\windows\mpi\intel64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64_win\mpirt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\ia32_win\mpirt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64_win\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\ia32_win\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi;C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Delft3D\w32\lib;C:\PROGRA~1\Deltares\w32\lib;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v82\runtime\win64;"C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\SysWOW64";C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\bin;C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\polyspace\bin;C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Roaming\npm;"C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem";C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\parallel_studio_xe_2017.5.060\compilers_and_libraries_2017\windows\bin\intel64;C:\Users\zk1357\iRIC\guis\prepost;
Set INCLUDE = C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\compiler\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.10150.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\\include\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\\include\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\\include\winrt;C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\extern\include;;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\compiler\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.10150.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\\include\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\\include\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\\include\winrt;C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\extern\include;;
Set LIB = C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\lib\intel64;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\compiler\lib\intel64;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\compiler\lib\intel64_win;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\Lib\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\Lib\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\Lib\10.0.10150.0\ucrt\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\\lib\winv6.3\um\x64;C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\lib\win64;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\lib\intel64;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\compiler\lib\intel64;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\compiler\lib\intel64_win;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\Lib\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\Lib\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\Lib\10.0.10150.0\ucrt\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\\lib\winv6.3\um\x64;C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\lib\win64;
Set LIBPATH = C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\compiler\Lib\Intel64;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\compiler\lib\intel64_win;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\\LIB\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\amd64;C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\extern\lib\win64;;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\compiler\Lib\Intel64;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\compiler\lib\intel64_win;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\\LIB\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\amd64;C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\extern\lib\win64;;
Options file details
-------------------------------------------------------------------
    Compiler location: C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows
    Options file: C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2019b\mex_FORTRAN_win64.xml
    CMDLINE200 : link  /nologo /manifest /INCREMENTAL:NO /DLL   /EXPORT:MEXFUNCTION /EXPORT:MEXFILEREQUIREDAPIVERSION C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\ero_dep_fortran.obj C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\Module.obj C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\prepare_bank_collapse.obj C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\LINEAR_ELASTIC_STIFFNESS.obj C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\FAILURE_CRITERION.obj C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\OUTPUT.obj C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\pardisonew.obj C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\fortran_mexapi_version.obj  "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\mkl\lib\intel64"   /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\extern\lib\win64\microsoft" libmx.lib libmex.lib libmat.lib  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib  ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /out:ero_dep_fortran.mexw64
    CMDLINE250 : mt -outputresource:ero_dep_fortran.mexw64;2 -manifest "ero_dep_fortran.mexw64.manifest"
    CMDLINE300 : del "ero_dep_fortran.exp" "ero_dep_fortran.lib" "ero_dep_fortran.mexw64.manifest" "ero_dep_fortran.ilk"
    COMPILER : ifort
    COMPFLAGS : /nologo /fpp /Qprec /MD /fp:source /assume:bscc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\mkl\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\extern\include"  /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -Qopenmp -Qmkl /integer-size:64
    COMPDEFINES : /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE
    OPTIMFLAGS : /O2 /DNDEBUG
    INCLUDE : -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\mkl\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\extern\include"
    DEBUGFLAGS : /Z7
    LINKER : link
    LINKFLAGS :  /nologo /manifest /INCREMENTAL:NO
    LINKTYPE : /DLL
    LINKEXPORT :  /EXPORT:MEXFUNCTION
    LINKEXPORTVER :  /EXPORT:MEXFUNCTION /EXPORT:MEXFILEREQUIREDAPIVERSION
    LINKLIBS : "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\mkl\lib\intel64"   /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\extern\lib\win64\microsoft" libmx.lib libmex.lib libmat.lib  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib  ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib
    LINKDEBUGFLAGS : /debug /PDB:"ero_dep_fortran.mexw64.pdb"
    LINKOPTIMFLAGS : 
    OBJEXT : .obj
    LDEXT : .mexw64
    SETENV : set COMPILER=ifort
                set COMPFLAGS=/c /nologo /fpp /Qprec /MD /fp:source /assume:bscc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\mkl\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\extern\include"  /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -Qopenmp -Qmkl /integer-size:64 /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE $MATLABMEX
                set OPTIMFLAGS=/O2 /DNDEBUG
                set DEBUGFLAGS=/Z7
                set LINKER=link
                set LINKFLAGS= /nologo /manifest /INCREMENTAL:NO /export:%ENTRYPOINT% /DLL "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\mkl\lib\intel64"   /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\extern\lib\win64\microsoft" libmx.lib libmex.lib libmat.lib  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib  ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib  /EXPORT:MEXFUNCTION
                set LINKDEBUGFLAGS=/debug /PDB:"%OUTDIR%%MEX_NAME%.mexw64.pdb"
                set NAME_OUTPUT=/out:"%OUTDIR%%MEX_NAME%%MEX_EXT%"
    FORTRANROOT : C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows
    VCROOT : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC
    SDKROOT : C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\
    KITSROOT : C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\
    MATLABROOT : C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b
    ARCH : win64
    SRC : "C:\Users\zk1357\Desktop\Evolution_Code_Doubon\ero_dep_fortran.F";"C:\Users\zk1357\Desktop\Evolution_Code_Doubon\Module.F";"C:\Users\zk1357\Desktop\Evolution_Code_Doubon\prepare_bank_collapse.F";"C:\Users\zk1357\Desktop\Evolution_Code_Doubon\LINEAR_ELASTIC_STIFFNESS.F";"C:\Users\zk1357\Desktop\Evolution_Code_Doubon\FAILURE_CRITERION.F";"C:\Users\zk1357\Desktop\Evolution_Code_Doubon\OUTPUT.F";"C:\Users\zk1357\Desktop\Evolution_Code_Doubon\pardisonew.F";"C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\extern\version\fortran_mexapi_version.F"
    OBJ : C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\ero_dep_fortran.obj;C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\Module.obj;C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\prepare_bank_collapse.obj;C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\LINEAR_ELASTIC_STIFFNESS.obj;C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\FAILURE_CRITERION.obj;C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\OUTPUT.obj;C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\pardisonew.obj;C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\fortran_mexapi_version.obj
    OBJS : C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\ero_dep_fortran.obj C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\Module.obj C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\prepare_bank_collapse.obj C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\LINEAR_ELASTIC_STIFFNESS.obj C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\FAILURE_CRITERION.obj C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\OUTPUT.obj C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\pardisonew.obj C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\fortran_mexapi_version.obj 
    SRCROOT : C:\Users\zk1357\Desktop\Evolution_Code_Doubon\ero_dep_fortran
    DEF : C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\ero_dep_fortran.def
    EXP : "ero_dep_fortran.exp"
    LIB : "ero_dep_fortran.lib"
    EXE : ero_dep_fortran.mexw64
    ILK : "ero_dep_fortran.ilk"
    MANIFEST : "ero_dep_fortran.mexw64.manifest"
    TEMPNAME : ero_dep_fortran
    EXEDIR : 
    EXENAME : ero_dep_fortran
    OPTIM : /O2 /DNDEBUG
    LINKOPTIM : 
    CMDLINE100_0 : ifort /c /nologo /fpp /Qprec /MD /fp:source /assume:bscc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\mkl\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\extern\include"  /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -Qopenmp -Qmkl /integer-size:64 /O2 /DNDEBUG "C:\Users\zk1357\Desktop\Evolution_Code_Doubon\ero_dep_fortran.F" /FoC:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\ero_dep_fortran.obj
    CMDLINE100_1 : ifort /c /nologo /fpp /Qprec /MD /fp:source /assume:bscc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\mkl\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\extern\include"  /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -Qopenmp -Qmkl /integer-size:64 /O2 /DNDEBUG "C:\Users\zk1357\Desktop\Evolution_Code_Doubon\Module.F" /FoC:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\Module.obj
    CMDLINE100_2 : ifort /c /nologo /fpp /Qprec /MD /fp:source /assume:bscc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\mkl\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\extern\include"  /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -Qopenmp -Qmkl /integer-size:64 /O2 /DNDEBUG "C:\Users\zk1357\Desktop\Evolution_Code_Doubon\prepare_bank_collapse.F" /FoC:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\prepare_bank_collapse.obj
    CMDLINE100_3 : ifort /c /nologo /fpp /Qprec /MD /fp:source /assume:bscc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\mkl\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\extern\include"  /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -Qopenmp -Qmkl /integer-size:64 /O2 /DNDEBUG "C:\Users\zk1357\Desktop\Evolution_Code_Doubon\LINEAR_ELASTIC_STIFFNESS.F" /FoC:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\LINEAR_ELASTIC_STIFFNESS.obj
    CMDLINE100_4 : ifort /c /nologo /fpp /Qprec /MD /fp:source /assume:bscc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\mkl\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\extern\include"  /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -Qopenmp -Qmkl /integer-size:64 /O2 /DNDEBUG "C:\Users\zk1357\Desktop\Evolution_Code_Doubon\FAILURE_CRITERION.F" /FoC:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\FAILURE_CRITERION.obj
    CMDLINE100_5 : ifort /c /nologo /fpp /Qprec /MD /fp:source /assume:bscc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\mkl\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\extern\include"  /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -Qopenmp -Qmkl /integer-size:64 /O2 /DNDEBUG "C:\Users\zk1357\Desktop\Evolution_Code_Doubon\OUTPUT.F" /FoC:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\OUTPUT.obj
    CMDLINE100_6 : ifort /c /nologo /fpp /Qprec /MD /fp:source /assume:bscc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\mkl\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\extern\include"  /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -Qopenmp -Qmkl /integer-size:64 /O2 /DNDEBUG "C:\Users\zk1357\Desktop\Evolution_Code_Doubon\pardisonew.F" /FoC:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\pardisonew.obj
    CMDLINE100_7 : ifort /c /nologo /fpp /Qprec /MD /fp:source /assume:bscc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\mkl\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\extern\include"  /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -Qopenmp -Qmkl /integer-size:64 /O2 /DNDEBUG "C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\extern\version\fortran_mexapi_version.F" /FoC:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\fortran_mexapi_version.obj
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Building with 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2017 for Fortran with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015'.
ifort /c /nologo /fpp /Qprec /MD /fp:source /assume:bscc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\mkl\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\extern\include"  /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -Qopenmp -Qmkl /integer-size:64 /O2 /DNDEBUG "C:\Users\zk1357\Desktop\Evolution_Code_Doubon\ero_dep_fortran.F" /FoC:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\ero_dep_fortran.obj
ifort /c /nologo /fpp /Qprec /MD /fp:source /assume:bscc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\mkl\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\extern\include"  /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -Qopenmp -Qmkl /integer-size:64 /O2 /DNDEBUG "C:\Users\zk1357\Desktop\Evolution_Code_Doubon\Module.F" /FoC:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\Module.obj
ifort /c /nologo /fpp /Qprec /MD /fp:source /assume:bscc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\mkl\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\extern\include"  /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -Qopenmp -Qmkl /integer-size:64 /O2 /DNDEBUG "C:\Users\zk1357\Desktop\Evolution_Code_Doubon\prepare_bank_collapse.F" /FoC:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\prepare_bank_collapse.obj
ifort /c /nologo /fpp /Qprec /MD /fp:source /assume:bscc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\mkl\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\extern\include"  /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -Qopenmp -Qmkl /integer-size:64 /O2 /DNDEBUG "C:\Users\zk1357\Desktop\Evolution_Code_Doubon\LINEAR_ELASTIC_STIFFNESS.F" /FoC:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\LINEAR_ELASTIC_STIFFNESS.obj
ifort /c /nologo /fpp /Qprec /MD /fp:source /assume:bscc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\mkl\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\extern\include"  /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -Qopenmp -Qmkl /integer-size:64 /O2 /DNDEBUG "C:\Users\zk1357\Desktop\Evolution_Code_Doubon\FAILURE_CRITERION.F" /FoC:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\FAILURE_CRITERION.obj
ifort /c /nologo /fpp /Qprec /MD /fp:source /assume:bscc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\mkl\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\extern\include"  /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -Qopenmp -Qmkl /integer-size:64 /O2 /DNDEBUG "C:\Users\zk1357\Desktop\Evolution_Code_Doubon\OUTPUT.F" /FoC:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\OUTPUT.obj
ifort /c /nologo /fpp /Qprec /MD /fp:source /assume:bscc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\mkl\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\extern\include"  /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -Qopenmp -Qmkl /integer-size:64 /O2 /DNDEBUG "C:\Users\zk1357\Desktop\Evolution_Code_Doubon\pardisonew.F" /FoC:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\pardisonew.obj
ifort /c /nologo /fpp /Qprec /MD /fp:source /assume:bscc -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\mkl\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\extern\include"  /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -Qopenmp -Qmkl /integer-size:64 /O2 /DNDEBUG "C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\extern\version\fortran_mexapi_version.F" /FoC:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\fortran_mexapi_version.obj
link  /nologo /manifest /INCREMENTAL:NO /DLL   /EXPORT:MEXFUNCTION /EXPORT:MEXFILEREQUIREDAPIVERSION C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\ero_dep_fortran.obj C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\Module.obj C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\prepare_bank_collapse.obj C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\LINEAR_ELASTIC_STIFFNESS.obj C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\FAILURE_CRITERION.obj C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\OUTPUT.obj C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\pardisonew.obj C:\Users\zk1357\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_155853875819566_16652\fortran_mexapi_version.obj  "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\mkl\lib\intel64"   /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2019b\extern\lib\win64\microsoft" libmx.lib libmex.lib libmat.lib  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib  ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /out:ero_dep_fortran.mexw64
  Creating ero_dep_fortran.lib and ero_dep_fortran.exp

mt -outputresource:ero_dep_fortran.mexw64;2 -manifest "ero_dep_fortran.mexw64.manifest"
Microsoft (R) Manifest Tool version 6.3.9600.17336

Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation 2012. 

All rights reserved.


del "ero_dep_fortran.exp" "ero_dep_fortran.lib" "ero_dep_fortran.mexw64.manifest" "ero_dep_fortran.ilk"
MEX completed successfully.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most probable reason is the incompatibility between the default integer size and MKL library interface version.

LP64 requires 4-byte integers, ILP64 requires 8-byte ones. `mex` by default adds the [`/integer-size:64`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-integer-size) option, thus making integers 8-byte long. But according to the [documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-windows-developer-guide-using-the-qmkl-compiler-option), with `/Qmkl` option the compiler links against LP64 libraries.

To fix the problem you need to link against `ILP64` libraries [explicitly](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor). To that aim remove `/Qopenmp /Qmkl` and use `-lmkl_intel_ilp64.lib -lmkl_intel_thread.lib -lmkl_core.lib libiomp5md.lib` link options.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I tried to add `-4I8` and use `mex COMPFLAGS="$COMPFLAGS -Qopenmp -Qmkl -4I8"` to compile, but it fails.  I also tried to run the code on the Intel Parallel Studio XE 2017 compiler and it works (I edited the question). Maybe there are some conflicts between Matlab mkl and intel mkl?

Comment: @kunzhao I'm not sure about conflicts. If you link statically, what kind of conflicts? Did you try to link against LP64 version? Did you try to call other MKL functions, BLAS, for example? Did you try to remove `-Qopenmp -Qmkl` options?

Comment: Or just do not use the ILP64 libraries. Why do you actually selected those? Do you have an actual specific reason to use them or did you just try them? Is it required by mex or something?

Comment: @Evg I only use the generated '.mexw64' without calling other MKL functions in Matlab. The 'pardiso' function is only called in Fortran code. What I know is that Matlab crashes without any error information when it calls 'pardiso' function in fortran code. If possible, I can show you the detailed code which crashes Matlab.

Comment: @Vladimir F Thanks for reply. I tried to use `mex COMPFLAGS="$COMPFLAGS -Qopenmp -Qmkl" '-IC:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\mkl\include' '-LC:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.5.267\windows\mkl\lib\intel64' ero_dep_fortran.F Module.F prepare_bank_collapse.F LINEAR_ELASTIC_STIFFNESS.F FAILURE_CRITERION.F OUTPUT.F pardisonew.F`. However, Matlab still crashes without any error information.

Comment: @Evg After I remove `-Qmkl`, it works!!!!!!! Thank you every much!!!! But I donot know why.....but it works!